# SwiftUI symbol effects animate on scrolling list only when in Stack view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-animation, sf-symbols

When: Embedding a Image with a symbol effect in a stack view in SwiftUI, and putting this in a List

Actual: The symbols animate when scrolling that item in and out of the view

Expected: The symbol doesn't animate until the value changes.

I have the following code which is boiled down from my actual code where the animating value is a @Model object property (other animations work fine when their animation's value is watching the same property.

I've boiled it down to the below examples:

The top example works as expected (no symbol animations on scroll)
The bottom example animates the symbols every time they scroll in to view

```swift
#Preview {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { index in
                Image(systemName: "square.3.layers.3d")
                    .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: index)
            }
        }
        
        List {
            ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { index in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "square.3.layers.3d")
                        .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This happens on Mac and iOS.

I'm running Xcode 15.3 RC2 but it also happens in Xcode 15.2

I've found the below example will happen whether it's a HStack, VStack or ZStack but seems fine in a Group.

I've tried adding a `id()` modifier to the HStack to give it an explicit identifier but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only substantial difference I can see between the two `List`s is that the `Image`s in the top list are assigned an id by the `ForEach`, but in the bottom list, the `ForEach` assigns its ids to the `HStack` instead.

Assigning an id manually to the images creates the same behaviour as the top list.

```
List {
    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "square.3.layers.3d")
                .symbolEffect(.bounce, value: index)
                .id(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah good shout! Sounds obvious when you know - I guess I got hung up on the fact that stacks seem to make a difference compared to group so guessing group is even more ephemeral than I thought and is completely ignored by the system.

Comment: @AdamCarter Yeah, `Group` is kind of like `EmptyView` in a certain sense.